# regex: contains at least 8 decimal digits

Tags: regex

I need regex to check if a string contains 8 decimal digits or more. It can contain anything else and the digits don't have to be consecutive.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: replaced "number" by "decimal digit" to match accepted answer.

Comment: try using http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx for creating your regex'

Comment: Perhaps you could try to formulate your next questions more precisely.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
/([^\d]*\d){8}/
```

Perhaps not the most elegant / efficient way to do it, but it works. Basically it will match eight decimals (optionally, with non-decimals between them). If there are more than eight, it will match too.

**EDIT**
As @Tomalak has pointed out, `[^\d]` equals `\D` by definition:

```
/(\D*\d){8}/
```

Comment: Alistar said 8 or more... `/([^\d]*\d){8,}/`

Comment: @CAFxX Yes if there are more than eight then there is also eight :)

Comment: You're right, I (wrongly) thought he also needed to capture them.

Comment: CAFxX Oh, I hope not :) (@Alistair, add the `,` if you need to capture the result - you will then need to strip out all non-decimals.)

Comment: But this will also match one number with a length of 8 or more.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, didn't think of that: `/(\D*\d){8}/`
@eisberg Will that be a problem?

Comment: @jensgram I do not know what the author really wants :-)

Comment: @eisberg Me neither, although I read it as very liberal in that the eight (or more) numbers can have anything in between. I.e., I assumed OP wanted to see if there were at least eight *digits* within a given string. I may be wrong, however.

Comment: @jensgram @Alistair Who knows :-)

Answer (score 5):

A tweak to allow the last character to be non-numeric:

```
/(\D*\d){8,}\D*/
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/\d{8,}/
```

Will match the 8 or more decimals requested by original poster

Answer (score 2):

```
/(?:\d+\D+){7,}\d+/
```

This will match at least 8 numbers with something other than numbers in between.

Comment: @Kobi I do not know if the author wants to match "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" or "11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88" kind of strings. There are so many possibilities.

Comment: @Kobi lets see what Alistair says :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?:(.+)?\d+(.+)?){8}/
```

Something like this?