# RegEx needs to be 8 or more characters

Tags: regex

I have a RegEx Expression:

```
^((0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]?(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.]?(19|20)\d\d)|((((0?[13578])|(1[02]))[- /.]?((0?[1-9])|([12][0-9])|(3[01]))|((0?[469])|(11))[- /.]?((0?[1-9])|([12][0-9])|(30))|(0?[2])[- /.]?((0?[1-9])|([1][0-9])|([2][0-8])))[- /.]?(19\d{2}|20\d{2}))|(((0?[2]))[- /.]?((0?[1-9])|([12][0-9]))[- /.]?((19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|2000))$
```

I want to make sure that it's at least 8 characters long.  I have tried this:
`{8,}`, `.{8,}` and variations of parens around the RegEx.  I'm probably missing something.

Some of the places I've looked for answers:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416250/regex-contains-at-least-8-decimal-digits)
[And Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot)

Those options still allow 6 characters when I need 8 or more
[Here is how I've been testing it](https://regex101.com/r/IbQO71/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple issues to fix:

- alternations (`|`) have priority over anchors (`^$`). To use it well, you must surround it with parenthesis: `^(a|b)$`
- To check the length in a regex, you can use a lookahead (`(?=)`): `(?=.{8,})`. It will ensure that the string is a least 8 char longs.

Combining that you get [this working example.](https://regex101.com/r/uleGX0/1)

Comment: I'm testing this now with some options but this looks great.  thank you so much!

Comment: excellent thank you for helping.  RegEx isn't something I have to deal with everyday